# How to use List, ArrayList and/and Array to create a 2-dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I'm fairly new to Java and having problems finding a structure to do the following.

I want a fixed length array. Each item to be a variable length array (or list) holding strings. So I've tried...

```
ArrayList<String>[] wordList = new ArrayList[maxWordLength];
```

I get a slapped wrist from Java for "Main.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations." and when I try to add an item I get "java.lang.NullPointerException"

```
wordList[oneWord.length()-1].add(oneWord);
```

How should I create my structure to keep Java happy?

Comment: That is because you have an array of null `ArrayLists`'s.

Comment: You are mixing ArrayList and Array, What you want seems to be just an array. May be just `String[] words = new  String[maxWordLength]`

Comment: @SomeDude but won't that just give me a one dimensional array? I need two dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't like arrays of generic types. (See [Restrictions on Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html) in the Java tutorials.) Instead, use a list of lists:

```
List<List<String>> wordList = new ArrayList<>(maxWordLength);
```

This creates a list with an initial capacity of `maxWordLength` that can contain lists of `String`. The initial size (as opposed to capacity) will be 0. Then you can add individual lists of strings to `wordList`. To avoid a `NullPointerException` later, you should fill `wordList` with empty lists to start with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxWordLength; i++) {
    wordList.add(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Finally, you can add a word to a particular list in `wordList` with:

```
wordList.get(oneWord.length() - 1).add(oneWord);
```

This doesn't force `wordList` to be of fixed length, but otherwise should meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:
Array with all elements as array of the Strings:

```
List<List<String>> listOfStringsArray = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> stringArray = Arrays.asList("String1", "String2");

listOfStringsArray.add(stringArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

`List` is the interface that concrete classes such as `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` must implement.

`ArrayList` is a `List` that is optimized for sequential reading, and adding, and is backed by an internal array.

`ArrayList<blah>` or `List<blah>` is a `List` that contains objects that inherits `blah` (or if it is an interface, objects that implement it.)

`ArrayList[]` is actually an array of `ArrayList`s  when you `new ArrayList[x]` that really means create an array of x length that contains `ArrayList`s.  Each of the `ArrayList`s are not assigned, and so it's an uninitialized object, by default, it is `null` in many compilers but you can't depend on that.

So, let's say you create this fixed length array that contains a variable length list.  you either have to do a loop over the array and say `wordList[i] = new ArrayList<String>()` or you have to do a nullcheck before you assign it and create a new `ArrayList` on each assignment